# Why does enabling multisampling on my app makes it render faster?

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, glkit, multisampling

I'm in a very awkward case where I see a noticeable boost in performance when I enable multisampling in my iOS app. Obviously I know that multisampling should decrease performance, but this time its behaving completely the opposite of what I would expect.

I enable multisampling by setting the GLKView.drawableMultisample to GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X. I clearly see the anti-aliasing effect it provides, so I'm not mistakenly confusing the two states.

When I enable multisampling, I get up to twice the frame rate, sometimes even more. First I thought perhaps the FPS shown in XCode might be wrong. Then I added my own FPS calculation code and I get the same results. I also noticed the Tiler Utilization goes up, from ~4-5% to like ~12-15% with multisampling enabled, with the exact same number of triangles, same shader.

That makes think there might be an error somewhere else. Nothing is coming out in the console (no warnings or errors) yet. I'm completely out of clues. Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you report overall CPU utilization and Renderer utilization? If you take a CPU Profile in instruments, does it look substantially different between the two modes?

Comment: One of my colleagues noticed something like this, although nothing anything like as dramatic. We couldn't think of a decent explanation.